# Unable to push item into array in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a `localStorage` where I am keeping a list of movies that the user has bought tickets for. I created an array for this purpose. The problem in that I am unable to push new values to this array in `localStorage`.

Code:

```
if(window.localStorage){
    if(localStorage.getItem('movies_list')){
        var movies_list = localStorage.getItem('movies_list');
        console.log("Movies List: " + localStorage.getItem('movies_list'));
        var movie = $("#movie_name").val();
        movies_list.push(movie);  // Error here
        localStorage.setItem('movies_list',movies_list);
    }
    else{
        var movies_list = new Array();
        var movie = $("#movie_name").val();
        movies_list.push(movie);
        localStorage.setItem('movies_list',movies_list);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object Movie 1 has no method 'push'
```

The `console.log()` is always returning `LIST: Movie 1`, seems like the next movie is not getting `pushed` into the array.

How do I push the new values to the array?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/21/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items you add/get from the localStorage are strings. So you need to JSON encode / decode them.

```
localStorage.setItem('movies_list', JSON.stringify(movies_list));
```

And

```
var movies_list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('movies_list'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kx9R6/1/

Comment: In your fiddle, its throwing an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token M `.

Comment: I refactored some of the code. Try again now, if it still gives that error, try removing `movie_list` from the local storage (using the Chrome Developer Tools for instance).

Comment: Sorry, its throwing the same error again. How do I remove `movie_list` from the local storage?

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of this: `movieListJson ? JSON.parse(movieListJson) : [];`

Comment: It's called a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which basically is the same as `if (movieListJson) { movie_list = JSON.parse(movieListJson); } else { movie_list = []; }`

Answer (score 2):

localStorage accpets and stores only strings, you can't directly save an array. Instead you can do JSON.stringify during saving and JSON.parse during retrieving.

```
var movies = ["movie1","movie2","movie3"];
//Saving
localStorage.movies_list = JSON.stringify(movies);
//Retrieving
var list = JSON.parse(localStorage.movies_list);
list.push("movie4");
```